# Enviar array por GET

Tags: javascript, array, lua

Estou a enviar por `GET` um *array* em JavaScript para outra pagina através de um `button` chamando a função. O problema é que ao enviar está em *string* e não em *array*. Quero passar esse *array* para a linguagem Lua. Este *array* contém valores. Exemplo:

Código em JavaScript:

```
var position_x = new Array();
position_x = [50,80,110];

function btn_onclick() {
   window.location.href = "page.htm?positionX="+position_x;
}

<input type=button value=pass onclick="return btn_onclick()" />
```

Na página 2:

```
tabela={}
for i=1, 3 do
    tabela[i] = GET["positionX"]
end
```

Quero voltar por numa tabela em Lua, porque assim insere os três valores em cada posição.

Comment: Que biblioteca para manipulação web você está usando? Ou seja, como está vindo este `GET`?

Comment: Vem através da barra de endereço, consigo ver os valores passados em parametro.

Comment: Mas esse `GET` não aparece do nada em Lua, precisa de alguma biblioteca, qual está usando?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu consigo montar a lógica para acessar a tabela que imagino vir da sua página mas isto depende de qual biblioteca está usando para receber os dados. Vou simular o dado recebido da página nas primeiras linhas:

```
GET = {}
GET["positionX"] = "50,80,110"
-- o codigo acima nao estaria presente no script, foi so para simular o recebimento dos dados
tabela={}
i = 1
for palavra in string.gmatch(GET["positionX"], '([^,]+)') do
    tabela[i] = palavra
    i = i + 1
end
-- codigo so para mostrar o resultado no console, ele nao faz parte do script
for k, v in pairs(tabela) do print(k, v) end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LNalo5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wzjiawar-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/GetHttp.lua).